# Tensorflow remap function

Tags: tensorflow

Does the Tensorflow have the image remap function?
I saw the OpenCV has [the remap function](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap):

> void remap(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray map1,
>   InputArray map2, int interpolation, int borderMode, const Scalar&
>   borderValue)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish by doing this in tensorflow instead of as a preprocessing step?

Comment: Because I need it do backpropagation.

Answer (score 5):

tf.contrib.resampler should do what you need.